# Is Satan's name Lucifer, Satanail, or Samuel?

Tags: satan, angels, demons, comparative-religion, name

In a few different English versions of the Bible, Isaiah 14:12 begins with something like:

> How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning! (KJV)

I thought, however, that Jesus was son of the morning.

Does anyone think this Isaiah passage was translated incorrectly, and that maybe it should be "son of *mourning*" instead of "son of the morning"?

What about Satanail (or *Satanial*?), or Samuel? Is either one of *these* more properly Satan's name?

Comment: What made you think Jesus was "son of the morning"?

Comment: Where does Samuel come into it???

Comment: I've tried to salvage the Question & I think I know exactly where its details are coming from, but it seems that clarifying it any further via Editing would be sneaking the Answer into the Question.

Answer (score 2):

Lucifer is simply a Latin word for light-bringer, light-bearer, Morning Star, or Day Star.  You can use any translation book or software (like Google) to look it up.

Lucifer is a description or adjective.  It is not a name.  Satan (Isa 14:12), the Angels (Job 38:7), and Jesus (Rev 2:28 and 22:16) were all called Morning Star.

The Bible clearly states that the Devil's name is Satan (which is adversary, accuser, or opponent in Hebrew).

Answer (score 2):

Isaiah 14:12 actually says, "Heylel, son of Shachar", or "Shining One, son of the Morning". Although traditionally treated as the fall of Satan, the taunt is intended for the king of Babylon, as found in Isaiah 14:3. 14:12 is understood as Venus, whose light in the morning is overlooked by the Sun's brightness.

This question about Jesus and Satan being the Morning Star are brought up often, but the association is superficial when you realize the authors, times, and audiences were different.